# Function 'Right'

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I try to convert output from function Right to an integer. I did the same with Left and it worked perfectly fine:

```
Public Function LEFT_NUM(cv As String, ch As Long)

cv = CStr(cv)
output = Left(cv, ch)

check = IsNumeric(output)

If check = True Then
    LEFT_NUM = CInt(output)
Else
    LEFT_NUM = output
End If
```

And this didn't work:

```
Public Function RIGHT_NUM(cv As String, ch As Long)

cv = CStr(cv)
output = Right(cv, ch)

check = IsNumeric(output)

If check = True Then
    RIGHT_NUM = CInt(output)
Else
    RIGHT_NUM = output
End If

End Function
```

**Edit**: If a value of a cell is 12345 (only a number) it returns the `#VALUE` error. If a value of a cell is 12345abc it returns part of this string as it should. the problem is it didn't work when in a cell is a number, only.

The Error emerges when I try to receive more than 4 digits (cell with a number only) by RIGHT_NUM(A1;5) and more than 5 by LEFT_NUM(A1;6).

Any ideas why?

Comment: *this didn't work:* What does that mean? Any Error raises? Why you say it is not working? Why you say first one works and second one not?

Comment: ... also provide test input.

Comment: If a value of a cell is 12345 (only number) it returns the #VALUE error. If a value of a cell is 12345abc it returns part of this string as it should be. the problem is it didn't work when in a cell is number only. The one for Left works fine in both cases.

Comment: Have a look at your `Tools->References`. Are there any in that list that say **MISSING**?

Comment: Works fine for me. How **exactly** did you call it?

Comment: As @Rory said - works fine.  Called both functions as worksheet functions and within VBA procedures using "12345abc" and giving `ch` values of both 3 and 9.

Comment: OK, now I see where the true problem is. Error emerge when I try to receive more than 4 digits (cell with a number only) by RIGHT_NUM(A1;5) and more than 5 by LEFT_NUM(A1;6).

Comment: Try using `CLng` instead of `CInt` to cast as Long instead of Integer.  Interger are only valid for -32,768 to 32,767 (Also, you haven't typed your Function either - probably `As Variant`?)

Comment: Great, it works! Many thanks ;) I understand that Long has it own limitations too but more important for me ist that I know where was the problem. What you mean by "typing function", how it should be done?

Comment: If your Problem is solved - maybe try to post a solution for any future googlers... also: if you define your function with a string as Input, you don't need another string conversion (cstr() is not necessary)

Comment: Look what you passed as `cv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extracted from comments**

answer supplied by Chronocidal

---

Change `CInt` to `CLng` as shown below:

```
Public Function LEFT_NUM(cv As String, ch As Long)
    cv = CStr(cv)
    output = Left(cv, ch)

    check = IsNumeric(output)

    If check = True Then
        LEFT_NUM = CLng(output) 'Changed on this line
    Else
        LEFT_NUM = output
    End If
End Function


Public Function RIGHT_NUM(cv As String, ch As Long)
    cv = CStr(cv)
    output = Right(cv, ch)

    check = IsNumeric(output)

    If check = True Then
        RIGHT_NUM = CLng(output) 'Changed on this line
    Else
        RIGHT_NUM = output
    End If
End Function
```